# Qooxdoo Firefox 47.0 'Unsupported client' warning

Tags: javascript, firefox, qooxdoo

I use Firefox with Firebug for testing Qooxdoo projects.

I discovered a warning message in Firebug´s console saying this:

> Unsupported client: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0! Assumed gecko version 1.9.0.0 (Firefox 3.0).

I think that is caused by Firefox 47.0, because earlier versions of Firefox did not show this. My Firebug version is 2.0.17 and my Qooxdoo version is 5.0.1.

How to get rid of this warning? And does this affect the functionality of Qooxdoo projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendering engine detection code is relying on vendor specific attributes. In this case mozilla decided to remove the public attribute window.navigator.mozApps which was available for gecko until version 46.

We already adressed this issue with https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues/8985 and solved it with commit https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/commit/3cca7bf283235e62c5e791f8c2cc6b0155130e4f in qooxdoo/master.

You may either checkout master from the github repo or patch your local copy manually.

There is a discussion regarding client engine detection on https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues/8994

You are invited to participate.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on the discussion about client engine detection. Looking forward for the new Qooxdoo version.

Comment: Would be cool if you accept the answer, of course only if it answers your question ;-)